# "Selection to Cursor" Why it's not working nomally

Tags: python, scripting, constraints, snapping

I made two UV Spheres like this

[image]

make Constraint-ChildOf

[image]

insert rotation keyframe of target

[image]

after few frame, I rotate target sphere and insert keyframe

[image]

And then, when I try to "Selection to Cursor"

[image]

The result is this....

[image]

as you can see. the sphere is not matched at cursor

What's wrong with it and How can I fix it?